# Install Django Taggit Inside Another App?

Tags: django, django-models, django-taggit

I am using [Django taggit](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html). Initially, I created a `tags` app and customized taggit slightly. It's not a lot of code and doesn't warrant it's own app (in my opinion) so I want to move the `tags` code to another app (let's call it `content`).

```
from content.utils import slugifier

class Tag(TagBase):
    """This is a replacement class for the Taggit "Tag" class"""

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("tag")
        verbose_name_plural = _("tags")
        app_label = "tags"

    def slugify(self, tag, i=None):
        slug = slugifier(tag)
        if i is not None:
            slug += "-%d" % i
        return slug

class TaggedItem(GenericTaggedItemBase, TaggedItemBase):
    # This tag field comes from TaggedItemBase - CustomTag overrides Tag
    tag = models.ForeignKey(
        Tag,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_items",
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("tagged item")
        verbose_name_plural = _("tagged items")
        app_label = "tags"
        index_together = [["content_type", "object_id"]]
        unique_together = [["content_type", "object_id", "tag"]]

class Content(PolymorphicModel):
    ...
    tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedItem, blank=True)
```

**My Problem**

When I go to `makemigrations`, I get this error:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Jarad\Documents\PyCharm\knowledgetack>python manage.py makemigrations
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
content.Content.tags: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'Tag', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

I think this error message is pretty clear and good. My app `content` has a model named `Content` which has a field named `tags`. The field defines a relationship with a model named `'Tag'`... but why isn't it installed? The code for the `Tag` model is literally right above the `Content` model?

Sidenote: I don't have `taggit` listed in my `INSTALLED_APPS` because I am customizing taggit and following the advice on [this page](https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom_tagging.html):

> Note: Including ‘taggit’ in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS list will
> create the default django-taggit and “through model” models. If you
> would like to use your own models, you will need to remove ‘taggit’
> from settings.py’s INSTALLED_APPS list.

#### My Question

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to change the `app_label = "tags"`.

You can remove it or change it to the actual app that you are moving the tags models to. Ex: `app_label = "content"`